# how to create random list in cmd batch file

Tags: batch-file, random, cmd

I have a list continents names in txt file, named conts.txt :

```
africa
america
asia
australia
europe
```

How I can create a batch file, where its create new txt file or recreate conts.txt file, with random order of continents names in the file.

Thanks and sorry for my bad english

**EDIT**: *Correction and apology to Liturgist*

I have batch script, it will create a file txt with list continents names by my order :

```
@echo off
set list=africa america asia australia europe
(for %%a in (%list%) do (
echo %%a
))>conts.txt
```

And with my basic sample script, how to create random order list names

Comment: Stackoverflow is not a code writing service. The methodology here is that you post the code you have written and describe how it does not meet the need. People here respond with suggestions to change the code so that it will work as desired. You may get some down votes. Your English is fine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create a second list with a random number, then sort that list based off the random number:

```
@echo off

setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

set list=africa america asia australia europe

rem Output the list first
(for %%a in (%list%) do (
rem Add a number to each line to sort by
set num=00000!random!
set num=!num:~-5!
echo !num!:%%a
))>conts_.txt

rem Run through the sorted file and output the second part
(for /f "usebackq tokens=2 delims=:" %%a in (`sort Conts_.txt`) do (
echo %%a
)) > conts.txt

rem Delete the temp file
del Conts_.txt
```

Comment: Thank you Anon Coward, your batch script works very well. Now I just modify your script, I have dozens or hundreds citys names in a one file txt, typed in order from A to Z. Next based that citys names file, I will create new txt file with random order citys names

Answer (score 2):

You could use a `for /L` loop to loop 1 iteration for each list item.  Within that loop, pick a random number between 1 and the number of continents in the list.  Call a function to return the continent corresponding to that random index, and to remove the continent from the list.  The `for /L` loop maintains the number of list items remaining.  This alleviates the need to write an intermediate temporary text file.

```js
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

set "list=africa america asia australia europe"

>continents.txt (
    for /L %%I in (5,-1,1) do (
        set /a idx = !random! * %%I / 32767 + 2
        call :getItem !idx! !list!
        echo !return!
    )
)

rem // end main runtime
goto :EOF

:getItem <idx> <list>
call set "return=%%~%~1"
set "list=!list:%return%=!"
goto :EOF
```

Notes: `for /L %%I in (5,-1,1)` counts 5,4,3,2,1.  `!random! * %%I / 32767` chooses a random number between 0 and `%%I` minus 1.  Adding two aligns the result with the `:getItem` function, which reserves its first argument for the random number.  This will work as long as the list starts with fewer than 9 elements.